# How to ignore the ampersand within an url for replacing a string in a batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, replace, cmd

In need to write a batch script, that replaces a variable with a URL in an html document. The URL comes from the users input.

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set /p vargs="Google Search: "
set "search=xxgs"
set "replace=%vargs%"
del output.html
for /F "delims=" %%a in (test.html) DO (
   set line=%%a
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   >> output.txt echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
   endlocal
)
```

If I paste a Google URL (e.g. https://www.google.de/search?q=test&oq=test&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i65l3j69i60.704j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), it'll returned an error, because of the ampersand.

How can i stop the interpretation of the ampersand and just replace my variable xxgs with the url?

Comment: You are better off doing such a replace in a different script like PowerShell, J-/vbscript. The angle brackets in a html will also have to be escaped/quoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the ampersand (and also some other characters) have special meaning to `cmd`, together with the fact that you are expanding the variable `replace` using normal (immediate) percent expansion (`%replace%`).

Since you are using this variable nested within a delayed expansion expression (namely the sub-string replacement `!line:%search%=%replace%!`), you cannot use delayed expansion for `replace`. However, you can delay the value expansion by using another `for /F` loop, as `for` variables are expanded also after special characters (like `^`, `&`, `(`, `)`, `"`, `<`, `>`, `|`) are handled:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "vargs="
set /p vargs="Google Search: "
set "search=xxgs"
set "replace=%vargs%"
> "output.txt" (
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("test.html") do (
        set "line=%%a"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        for /F "delims=" %%b in (""!replace!"") do (
            echo(!line:%search%=%%~b!
        )
        endlocal
    )
)
```

The inner `for /F` loop receives the value of `!replace!`, which is available in `%%~b` later; since `%%~b` is still expanded before the actual sub-string replacement of `line` is done, it provides the expected output. The outer pair of quotation marks in the expression `""!replace!""` is removed by `for /F` and tells it to consider the remainder as a literal string (as there is no `usebackq` option); the inner pair of `""` is processed by `for /F` together with the value of `replace` and is later removed by the `~` modifier in `%%~b`; with this trick, the loop even executes in case `replace` is empty, as the string appears as `""` to `for /F` (note that the loop ignores empty strings/lines), so the script works even if the user enters nothing in the prompt. If you do not want this behaviour and skip the sub-string replacement upon empty user input, simply remove the outer pair of quotation marks `""` and replace `%%~b` with `%%b`.

Note that exclamation marks in the value of `replace` still lead to unexpected results, because `for` variables are expanded before delayed expansion is processed, which consumes `!` characters.

In addition to that, I changed the following:

- the variable `vargs` is cleared before the prompt `set /P vargs=`, so when the user enters nothing, `vargs` is truly empty, as `set /P` keeps the previous value in case of no input;
- instead of writing every single line to the output file, I redirected the entire `for /F` loop structure to the file `output.txt` once only; since this allows to use the `>` operator rather than `>>`, the output file does not have to be deleted in advance any more (although you deleted `output.html` rather than `output.txt`, but I assume this is just a typo);
- I added the `usebackq` option to `for /F` and quoted the file path/name, so it may even contain white-spaces or special characters;
- the syntax of `set` within the loop structure is changed to the quoted one `set "line=%%a"`;